# Pom file configuration in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-3, pom.xml

In jenkins I have configured maven job. Configured "Root POM" with

```
(/home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/) and also tried with (/home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/pom.xml).
```

**But it is saying no such file or directory.**

```
/home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/pom.xml
```

**No such file: ‘/home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/pom.xml’**

But the files are there.

```
[sdiuser@usboss-sdijenkins Build-Release]$ ls -lrt /home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/
total 12
-rw-rw-r--. 1 sdiuser sdiuser  767 Aug 31 03:01 pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x. 4 sdiuser sdiuser 4096 Aug 31 03:01 src
drwxrwxr-x. 7 sdiuser sdiuser 4096 Aug 31 03:02 target
```

**Jenkins Output**

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/maven-test/workspace
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the missing `x` right on the folder, so Jenkins is not allowed to search the directory. Try `chmod +x /home/sdiuser/Build-Release/maven_artifactid` and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Jenkins user does not have rights to access folder where pom.xml is stored.

Answer (score 0):

As the inline "Root POM" documentation mentions, your POM should be in the Jenkins workspace, and any path you enter should be relative.

In general with Jenkins, you should not hardcode paths — you should let Jenkins check out a local copy of the code into the build workspace, i.e. use the Git plugin or Subversion plugin, or whatever you use.

Assuming your project root is the `Build-Release` folder, once you configure Jenkins to check that out, you can set `maven_artifactid/pom.xml` as your Root POM and Jenkins should find it.

Answer (score 0):

put your pom inside workspace.Jenkins will find it automatically, else there might be some Access issues with the file or folder path